# How to display sum count s in Indian format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How to display sum count s in Indian format 
Example -1,00,00,000

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/api/sum().js"></script>



drawCallback: function () {
              var api = this.api();
              $("#sum").html(
                "Total Amount: "+api.column( 4, {page:'current'} ).data().sum().toLocaleString()
              );
            }
            
            <p id="sum"></p>
```

Comment: Maybe with [AccountingJS](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it quite easily by passing a locale to toLocaleString, in case it doesn't pick up the one you want:

```js
$(function() {
  var num = -100000000;
  $("#sum").html(num.toLocaleString('en-IN'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="sum"></p>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString for more details.